# Android TurnBasedMultiplayer calling takeTurn() doesnt generate a onTurnBasedMatchReceived()

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am writing a Multiplayer game using `Google's TurnBasedMultiplayer API` and calling `takeTurn()`. I have three players in the game, and besides the player who is calling takeTurn, I am finding that one player receives the update and `onTurnBasedMatchReceived()` is correctly called, yet the other player doesn't receive the update, `onTurnBasedMatchReceived()` is not called.

Can someone supply me with a possible reason not all players are receiving the updates? I note that the player who doesn't receive the update needs to go back to the Match Inbox and choose the relevant match again, and then it can be seen that the game is in fact updated.

Comment: If you have correctly configured your [`OnTurnBasedMatchUpdatedReceivedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener.html), it is true that all players in the game should be updated when you call `takeTurn()` and update the match state.  Can you share some code for how you are registering these listeners and also how you are calling `takeTurn()`?  That may shed some light on your specific issue.

Comment: @Override
    public void onTurnBasedMatchReceived(TurnBasedMatch match) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "A match was updated.", TOAST_DELAY).show();
   updateMatch(match);
        
    }

Comment: Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.takeTurn(getApiClient(), mMatch.getMatchId(),
                mTurnData.persist(),nextParticipantId).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                processResult(result);
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Is the player who is not receiving the updates completely in the match? A player who hasn't accepted an invitation won't receive calls to `onTurnBasedMatchUpdated`.

Additionally, when a player receives an invitation, this comes to an *invitation* listener, not a match updated listener. If you're trying to use the match updated listener for both, that would also explain why you're not getting an update.

Comment: Yes, the player is completely in the match. It is not an invitation. Thanks for the query though. I am suspecting that it is a syncing issue on the Samsung that was being used, but I can't find where to set the auto sync to on on the device, so I can't verify this and answer my own question yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the listener.  I use code like this on my main activity...

public class GameScreen extends Activity implements OnInvitationReceivedListener,
          OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener {
...
}